# Network shortcut on Windows 7 taskbar fails

Tags: windows-7, windows

Shortcuts to my network drive on the taskbar now initially fail. "Now" means that this is only a few-weeks-old problem (mid-may 2017). It worked fine for several years before, no failures.

"Fail" means that when I click on them (1 shortcut to drive, 1 to folder w/in drive), "user/my documents" opens. This is a temporary/permanent failure, in that if I click on shortcut on the desktop, the network drive and folders open -- not only from desktop shortcut, but now open properly from the taskbar shortcut -- that is the "temporary" part.

"Permanent" means that reboot brings back the same problem.

Here's the command line

```
explorer "S:\shared folder buffalo"
```

Fixes?

Comment: "Persistent" would be a better word.

Comment: Has the server changed IP addresses? Can you browse to the UNC path of the share?